# SOCKET.IO IN express whit EC2 AWS throws "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established."

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, socket.io

I'm creating a http Socket.io server inside of an express server with something like this:

```
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3001;
const server = express();
const server2 = http.createServer(server);
const io = socketIo(server2, {
 pingTimeout: 3600000 
 });
server.listen(port);
```

I was able to get a `101 status` code in my localhost connection.
But at the time I deploy my code to a AWS EC2 instance, it throws the following error:

> WebSocket connection to 'ws:/socket.io/EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

**Client side**

```
this.socket = io("/", {
      transports: ["websocket"]
    });
```

Comment: where is your socket's code? Please share your index.js file where you write code which opens socket.

Comment: I already edited the post

Comment: have you tried to set pingInterval as in socketIo's options?

Comment: I tried it, but it keeps closing at the same time